# Is using a 3-second CSS transition to move an element on-screen ADA compliant?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Is using CSS transition to move text from off screen to a place on the screen ADA (Americans with Disability Act) compliant?

```
h1 {
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      animation: heading;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
@keyframes heading {
      0% {top: -50px;}
      100% {top: 30vh;}
}
```

https://codepen.io/KuanaxBon/full/OJVLOmm

Comment: Try with Chrome Vox screenreader extension but as long as the element is not display none, it's in the dom, it will get read so the animation should be fine.

Comment: To the close-voters: asking whether specific code is compliant with a published specification is not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parts of WCAG that are applicable here are [SC 2.2.2 pause, stop, hide](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#x2-2-2-pause-stop-hide) and [SC 2.3.3 motion from interaction](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#animation-from-interactions).

In your example provided, the animation is automatically started on page load, so it doesn't require *interaction*, and as such you can bypass 2.2.3 if you want.

Similarly, 2.2.2 specifies that it's only applicable if an animation lasts longer than 5 seconds, and your example is 3 seconds.

Non-sighted visitors shouldn't have a problem with the animations, as long as the DOM order is correct.

So, in my interpretation, your example will be ***compliant*** with WCAG 2.1 as-is, but if you want to make it ***more useful*** for real human visitors, I would recommend implementing the CSS [reduce-motion query](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/css/C39) for visitors who may have issues with moving text. For some people, moving text on a webpage can cause vertigo, dizziness, and/or nausea.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is extremely helpful.